# How to sync 2 folders with all subfolders without overwriting

Tags: linux, copy, directory, subdirectory

I'm in linux (Ubuntu 12.04). I have 2 folders, folder A and folder B. (both have the same subfolders). I would like to copy all files from folder B (and from all subfolders) which are not in folder A and paste them in folder A in the appropiate subfolder, using a single terminal command.
Without overwriting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
cp -r -n ./B/* ./A
```